# Open folder in Git Bash with Sublime Text 2 on Windows

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm looking for a solution to be able to right-click on any folder in the side bar, of Sublime Text 2 on Windows, and select "Open with Git Bash" so that Git Bash opens with that folder, ready for my git commands.

I've tried the Open With functionality with the Side Bar Enhancements plugin, but no luck.

Oh, and I've tried the "Git" plugin for ST2. It's not what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me on Windows 7

Create the following files under `Packages/User`

`git_bash.py`

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class GitBashCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self, **args):
        dir = args["dirs"][0]
        self.window.run_command("exec", {"cmd": ["start", "sh", "--login", "-i"], "shell": True, "working_dir": dir})
        self.window.run_command("hide_panel", {"panel": "output.exec"})

    def is_visible(self, **args):
        return len(args["dirs"]) > 0
```

`Side Bar.sublime-menu`

```
[
    { "caption": "Git bash...", "command": "git_bash", "args": { "dirs": []} }
]
```

Make sure to add you Git Bash bin folder avaiable in the Windows PATH, on windows 8 its per default ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\

http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

Comment: bonus points for info on how to run the Git Bash as an administrator?

Comment: @blisstdev perhaps you could wrap the `sh` command inside a `runas` command giving it some user with admin privileges. from cmd this seems to do it for me: `start runas /savecred /user:administrator "sh --login -i"`

Comment: Thanks @urraka!  Doesn't open UAC like I would want but it certainly works.  I can work around it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with no extension name and put this:

```
#!/bin/sh
"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" $1 &
```

Then, open your Git folder > bin, paste it there.

Now, you can do

```
subl sample_directory
```